# Accidentally hid the run and debug button, how do I get it back?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I was messing around with the "Run and Debug" function of VSCode, and I right clicked on the run and debug button and accidentally hid it. I don't remember what the button I clicked said, but it disappeared right after I clicked it. I've looked through all the menus, and searched online, but I wasn't able to unhide the button.

Here's an image of where the button used to be:

[image: where the button was]

Here's what it used to look like and what I'm trying to get back:

[image]

Comment: @Mark That just enables/disables the Run and Debug tab, not the actual button that starts a debugging session. Turning it on and off again didn't help either.

Comment: I've added a new image to show what I mean

Comment: I see now, right-click on the gear icon to the right.  Enable `Start Debugging`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right-click on the gear icon to the right of the `Run and Debug` header. Enable the `Start Debugging` option.  The ability to hide a lot of buttons and icons was recently added to vscode.  In general, right-clicking something in the same view will give you the option to re-enable anything you hid.

You can also trigger the command: `View: Reset all Menus` - which will re-enable **All** changes you might have made to menus and icon buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Debug panel on the right (the panel with Variables / Watch / Call Stack), then the Run & Debug button will appear at the top-left of that panel somewhere on the right.

You can drag that button to the left Activity Bar and it will pin there.